# Creating Jenkins account timeout

Tags: apache, google-chrome, ubuntu, jenkins

i just managed to get Jenkins running on my Ubuntu instance in AWS.
the dashboard works and its looks good, my only problem is that when i try to enable security, i chose Jenkins own users database, i am asked to create a user, i insert the user name, password, full name and email then when i hit sign up i get an `ERR_TIMED_OUT`

I reinstalled jenkins on twice and i am still facing the same problem.

Does anyone have suggestions on why its giving me a timeout error?

is there a way to add users from my terminal?